# why python delete object cost a long time?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use `cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)` to capture pictures from url.

I used a map to hold several `cv2.VideoCapture`, the key is the name of url and the value is `cv2.VideoCapture`. And when the url is invalid(**For example, my video stream is not pushed anymore**), I want to delete it. But it takes a lot of time to block the thread.

I also tried

```py
# idle_stream is the name of url, and key is cv2 object
self.map.pop(idle_stream)  

or

self.map[idle_stream] = None
```

Both will block about 10s or more. How can I achieve non-blocking thread deletion?

Comment: What makes a URL invalid in this case? I would check if my URLs are valid before creating `cv2.VideoCapture` objects to avoid the cost of deleting them. I would also suggest you to change your title to something more specific to your problem and not so generic.

Comment: @pazitos10 I capture a rtmp video and which will not pushing anymore, then I need to delete it

Comment: since this isn't a "**minimal reproducible example**", I would suggest that you provide such a thing. your current question contains two lines of code. that code is insufficient to debug your issue.